# Appcelerator Arrow error after nodeJS upgrade: Module version mismatch. Expected 47, got 46

Tags: node.js, appcelerator, appcelerator-cli

After I upgraded NodeJS and NPM to 3.x.x, when I run "Appc run" command for my Appcelerator Arrow application, I get the following error:

[Error: Module version mismatch. Expected 47, got 46.]

Interestingly, the console does NOT show any further details as to which module is throwing the error.

I have tried removing all node modules and then run "npm install" but this error won't go away. Any advice would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because different versions of node has different api compatibility (for node, not appc).

The easiest was to fix this is to re-install the appc command line tools again using the command: `appc use latest --force`.

Comment: Actually, `appc use latest` will only select the most recent version if its already installed. You need to add `--force` to force a fresh install.